# Outlook 2016 crashing while trying to download messages

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-outlook

Outlook keeps crashing when open and it connected to the server and trying to download emails on Windows 10 for a week now. Errors are given below for reference. Please advise what is the best way to fix the issue.

**Windows: 21H1 Build 19043.1348

Outllok/Office: 2016 MSO (Version 2110 Build 16.0.14527.20270) 64-bit**

Most of time we get below error and Event Id 1000 and 1005 are recorded.

> Windows cannot access the file C:\Windows\System32\C_949.NLS for one
> of the following reasons: there is a problem with the network
> connection, the disk that the file is stored on, or the storage
> drivers installed on this computer; or the disk is missing. Windows
> closed the program Microsoft Outlook because of this error.
>
> Program: Microsoft Outlook File: C:\Windows\System32\C_949.NLS

Tried to run Outlook in safe mode but no help. Reinstalled Office with no help.
Finally reinstalled Windows and office but still no help.

1000:

> Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version:
> 16.0.14527.20276, time stamp: 0x6186f169 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.19041.1348, time stamp: 0x76fcd692
> Exception code: 0xc0000006 Fault offset: 0x0000000000011e96 Faulting
> process id: 0x20b4 Faulting application start time: 0x01d7da1aff5e9d0d
> Faulting application path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft
> Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE Faulting module path:
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
> 4ac83f51-b729-4fde-b0e3-47c5e05d43c0 Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

1005:

> Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 16.0.14527.20276,
> time stamp: 0x6186f169 Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
> 10.0.19041.1348, time stamp: 0x76fcd692 Exception code: 0xc0000006 Fault offset: 0x0000000000011e96 Faulting process id: 0x20b4 Faulting
> application start time: 0x01d7da1aff5e9d0d Faulting application path:
> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE Faulting
> module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll Report Id:
> 4ac83f51-b729-4fde-b0e3-47c5e05d43c0 Faulting package full name:
> Faulting package-relative application ID:

**Edit-1:**
I also removed the existing profile from control panel Mail and created a new profile before reinstalling Office but that did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Tried to run Outlook in safe mode but no help. Reinstalled Office with
> no help. Finally reinstalled Windows and office but still no help.

I am using the same 64-bit version here.

The actions you took will not normally affect the Outlook Profile.

Make sure you have a backup of your email, and make sure you know how to remake your email account

Open Control Panel, Mail.

Open the Profile Setting, and delete the Outlook Profile.

Restart the computer, go back and make a new Outlook Profile. Make sure you point it to your existing Email file and it should now work.

[image: Outlook 2016 Profile]

.

If emails are maintained on a server, you might also wish to talk to the people who support the server.

One of our personal accounts is hosted on Outlook 365 Exchange and the password is a special password generated from the Web Account. It does not crash but it needs the special password.

Finally, you said:

> same email works fine if configured in a separate computer so I am
> suspecting issues on the machine.

So then reinstall Windows again, only this time, back everything up, format, and do a completely fresh install of Windows. Do not use Windows Reset.

Comment: Thanks John. I tried to delete the Profile and restarted and created a new profile still it did not work. Infact I created a new profile as emails are on the server so it will get synced but did not pointed to existing file.

Comment: You might wish to also ask the Server Support people. I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks John, The machine has same issue with any email that we configure and same email works fine if configured in a separate computer so I am suspecting issues on the machine. That was the reason I did reinstalled Windows by wiping the windows drive, where the outlook datafile was set to saved.

Comment: I amended my answer. Make sure you have a complete backup, format the disk and start completely fresh with Windows. Do not use Windows Reset

Comment: Yes, I used windows RESET, that may be the issue and a clean format and install may solve the issue.

Comment: Reset does not clear everything so clean format and install will work

Comment: Agree with John, considering the issue is related to the specific machine, the problem should be solved after completely fresh install of windows. Look forward to the update of your issue.

Comment: Thanks John doing a clean format and install resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the update and great that all is working now.